# Spring 4.3.7 is throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, weblogic12c

When I am migrating from spring 4.3.4 to 4.3.7 I am facing NoclassDefined error after adding Jackson-core dependency

> Caused By: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
> Failed to instantiate
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenter

I tried to add jackson-core

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

dependency also but no luck

Any one who can shed some light on this would be appreciated.

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: The `DefaultIndenter` class was introduced in Jackson 2.5.  Perhaps some other part of your project is bringing in a dependency on an earlier version lacking the class.  It might be a transitive dependency through some library.  Try running `mvn dependency:tree` and looking for older Jackson versions in the output.

Comment: give the snapshot of your project dependencies

Comment: @Sergey/Chris  we have multi module environment where we are inheriting dependencies from other pom's as well.Everywhere I can see that the dependency version for Jackson-core is same one more time I will clean the repositories and update you guys .Thanks for your prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, with Spring 4.3.22.RELEASE and jackson-databind 2.2.3, I only had to upgrade to 2.9.8 and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else found this through Google and if You are using Spring Boot, here is what solved the problem for me. Try setting the parent of Your pom file (i.e. Maven project):

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

This will set the `spring-boot-starter` version to 2.0.2, and not the 1.x, which was default (at least for me).

Following [the comment of Chris Nauroth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060443/spring-4-3-7-is-throwing-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-c?rq=1#comment77099261_45060443), I've used the `mvn dependency:tree` and saw that the 1.x version of Spring Boot used the 2.4.x version of Jackson, whereas `spring-boot-starter` version 2.x uses Jackson 2.5 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```