# HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable [Streaming huge data from backend using spring 4.3.x + Java 8]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-8

I am using Spring mvc 4.3.x, java 8, Tomcat 7

**CODE:**

```
@Controller
public class StreamRecordsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/streamrecords", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, 
            produces = "application/octet-stream")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> export() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Ankur\\sample.pdf");
        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
            Files.copy(file.toPath(), outputStream);
        };
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=generic_file_name.pdf")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(responseBody);
    }
}
```

**EXCEPTION:**

[image]

**POSTMAN SNAPSHOT**

[image]
**QUESTION:**

What am I missing here ?

Comment: It says, that client (eg browser) expects some sort of content X (via `Accept` header eg. `application/json`) to be sent by server, but server does not provide such content on given endpoint (eg produces only XML).

Comment: Try without any `Accept` header in postman.

Comment: @Antoniossss You are a genius. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to sort this out which is now helping me stream huge data from backend to Frontend using **Spring 4.3.x** as mentioned in my post. Below are the points to guide you to execute the program successfully.

Below procedure is so effective that you can even paginate huge data at the back end (can be hibernate, Mongo-java-driver, cassandra java driver, etc)and keep on streaming the data unless your db operation is complete. In some domains like Manufacturing, Insurance, Logistics etc, you need such utility where end user expects quiet huge data from server in the form of CSV, JSON etc to analyse the raw data.

1. Add one more annotation `@EnableWebMvc` above your controller class.
2. When you add above annotation, the code will break at runtime, you can see in `catalina.log`, this error : [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45060443/3296607)
3. To fix this you will need to add below jar dependency in your `pom.xml`

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.9.8</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Now, add `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` in `web.xml` under `<servlet>` tag as below example,

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       <async-supported>true</async-supported>
   </servlet>
   ```

Below is the code for both FILE Streaming Download and Data Stream support.

**DATA STREAM CODE:**

```
package com.emg.server.controller.rest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class StreamRecordsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/streamrecords")
    @ResponseBody
    public StreamingResponseBody export() {
        return new StreamingResponseBody() {
            @Override
            public void writeTo (OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    out.write((Integer.toString(i) + " - ")
                                        .getBytes());
                    out.flush();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**FILE STREAM CODE:**

```
package com.emg.server.controller.rest;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class StreamRecordsController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/streamrecords", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> export() {
         File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Ankur\\sample.pdf");
            StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
                Files.copy(file.toPath(), outputStream);
            };
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=generic_file_name.pdf")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .body(responseBody);
        }
}
```

**OUTPUT for both the streaming style**

[image]

> **NOTE:** I execute both programs individually, deployed and tested it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing 2 things:

First of all, your code is returning `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` as content type. It would be nice, if you will tell spring that `export()` method is producing that type. You can do this with `produces` attribute of `@RequestMapping`.

Second thing is that you browser is not asking for `APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` - you can see that by `Accept` header value. `APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` maps to `application/octet-stream` - your request from browser will need to include it within `Accept` header value, so Spring will be able to recognize, which method should be called in your controller.

Edit: after you will fix it, take a look on `@RestController` annotation that can be used instead of `@Controller` - you will not have to add `@ResponseBody` annotation, as it will be included by default. Look also to `@GetMapping` that is an overlay for `@RequestMapping` annotation for HTTP GET methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and comments. I will update you on same shortly.

Comment: Still the output is same, Please find the above updated code.

Answer (score 1):

406 Not Acceptable

The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

Try use the Produces annotation in your controller method:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

Comment: Still the output is same, Please find the above updated code.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening to you might be a Spring MVC bug. With browsers & it also varies among browsers - Accept header in request is mandatory with correct values. You might get a different behavior in different browser and your code might work in swagger UI.

As per your screenshot, your Accept header doesn't match with response type , it should be `*/*` as your code is special in the sense that you don't take any input which is a rare scenario in REST world.

So I suggest to add consumes in your mapping like below & see if it works,

`@RequestMapping(value = "/streamrecords", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)`

and make sure that Accept header in request carries value - `*/*`.

Comment: Thank you Sabir, Will update you shortly on this.... Let me check doing above changes.

Comment: Still the output is same, Please find the above updated code.

Comment: What is your Rest client ? Some JavaScript / Angular etc code or anything else ? Try setting `Accept` header value to `*/*` in your client as it has to be set in request header.

Comment: My Rest Client is postman and web browser. If I remember, I did try `*/*`.... things did not work out

Comment: Swagger is firing this - `curl -X GET "http://localhost:7001/streamrecords" -H "accept: */*"`   & its working . Does your browser showed Accept header value to be `*/*` after your code changes or value remained same as you shown in initial screenshot ?

Comment: Swagger gives me option to download the file & same is the case in Postman if I set `Accept=*/*` i.e. Http Status is 200 from both clients. If Accept header value remains same even after you explicitly set that header value, you need to post that code & postman screen shots.

Comment: Did you use Spring Boot? If yes then I am not using Spring Boot here. It is pure Spring MVC 4.x

Comment: Yes, I am on Spring Boot version - `1.5.2.RELEASE`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you tell me how can we achieve this without using Spring Boot.

Comment: In that case, it might be the case of missing / incompatible json libraries - that is just the starting point. I suggest to upload your full code somewhere & provide link.

Answer (score 1):

This error says that client (eg browser) expects some sort of content X (via Accept header eg. application/json) to be sent by server, but server does not provide such content on given endpoint (eg produces only XML).

In your case, you are "accepting" multiple formats,but none of them is `application/octet-stream` and that is what you have declared that server will return in `@RequestMapping(produces = "application/octet-stream")`annotation. Include that in your `Accept` header browser side.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you tell me how to include Accept header in chrome browser?